# Jupyter Notebook - Erros with retrieving numpy

Tags: pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

Here is the error message that gets returned when trying to import pandas as pd

---

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7dd3504c366f> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>
     14 
     15 if missing_dependencies:
---> 16     raise ImportError(
     17         "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
     18     )

ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
- Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
- If you have already done that, then:
  1. Check that you expected to use Python3.9 from "/usr/bin/python3.9",
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.17.4" you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.

Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

---

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04
Python3.9

I've checked to find that Python3.9 is running appropriately.
I've uninstalled and installed numpy and anaconda
I've tried creating and running a virtual environment to use jupyter in

I don't know what else to do, or where my problem is. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved my issue.

When opening a new notebook in Jupyter notebook, it prompts you to open a Python3 notebook or Python3.9.0 64 bit notebook. Although Python3.9.0 64 bit is the most current edition, and one I had downloaded, it wasn't what I had installed. When opening a Python3 book I was able to import pandas just fine (I got no error message about not being able to open numpy)